# update column based on two columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a weird problem.

I have a rather large database with two tables. I need to change a column's contents from a name to an ID that already exists in another table.

Example:

I have a table that contains a column "Name"

the name column has the persons "lastname, firstname" as shown

```
     Name   | othercolumn
Smith, John |
```

I would like to change the contents of the name column to the staffID associated with the persons name.

The staff table is

```
staffID | firstName | lastName
  1          john        smith
```

My end result should be

```
Name | othercolumn
1    |
```

I've tried all sorts of joins and concats, but can't seem to get it down with my limited mysql knowledge. Is there a way to do this without having to do it manually? The comma seems to give me alot of grief. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be very careful about this.  First, I assume that `StaffId` is a number.  So, add a column to the table:

```
alter table t add StaffId int;
```

Then, update this column:

```
update t join
       staff s
       on t.name = concat_ws(',', s.lastname, s.firstname)
    set t.StaffId = s.StaffId;
```

Note that after you have done this, you may still have `StaffId` values that are `NULL`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.StaffId is null;
```

These are the names that are not in the `staff` table.  They require more work.  When you are done, you can drop the `name` column.